# How to reconstruct this Numpy Structured Array?

Tags: python, numpy, simulink

I have a Simulink (.mat) data structure that I've been able to read with the python function scipy.io.loadmat().  I'd like to create this data structure programmatically in python but I haven't been able to get the nesting correct.  Upon reading from the .mat file, the data structure looks as follows:

```
>>> mat['rtp']['internal']
    array( [[
        array( [[ (
            array( [[
                array( [[
                    (array(['Br'], dtype='<U2'), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[2]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
                    (array(['Ari'], dtype='<U3'), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[3]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8))
                ]],
                dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('transitionIdx', 'O'), ('mapIdx', 'O'), ('isStruct', 'O')] )
            ]],
            dtype=object), )
        ]],
        dtype=[('tunedParameters', 'O')] )
    ]],
    dtype=object )
```

I can create the interior (variable a) of the data structure with the following code:

```
dt = np.dtype([('name','O'),('transitionIdx','O'),('mapIdx','O'),('isStruct','O')])

all_entries = np.empty( 0, dtype=dt)

# Br PARAMETERS:
paramName = 'Br'
transitionIdx = 1
paramIdx = 2
isStruct = 0

new_entry = np.empty( 1, dtype=dt)
new_entry['name'] = [np.array( np.array([paramName]))]
new_entry['transitionIdx'] = [np.array([np.array([transitionIdx])],dtype=np.uint8)]
new_entry['mapIdx'] = [np.array([np.array([paramIdx])],dtype=np.uint8)]
new_entry['isStruct'] = [np.array([np.array([isStruct])],dtype=np.uint8)]

all_entries = np.append(all_entries, new_entry)

# Ari PARAMETERS:
paramName = 'Ari'
transitionIdx = 1
paramIdx = 3
isStruct = 0

new_entry = np.empty( 1, dtype=dt)
new_entry['name'] = [np.array( np.array([paramName]))]
new_entry['transitionIdx'] = [np.array([np.array([transitionIdx])],dtype=np.uint8)]
new_entry['mapIdx'] = [np.array([np.array([paramIdx])],dtype=np.uint8)]
new_entry['isStruct'] = [np.array([np.array([isStruct])],dtype=np.uint8)]

all_entries = np.append(all_entries, new_entry)

print( f"all_entries = {all_entries}" )
print( f"all_entries.dtype = {all_entries.dtype}" )

a = np.array([all_entries,])
print( f"a = {a}" )
print( f"a.dtype = {a.dtype}" )
```

Output:

```
a = [[(array(['Br'], dtype='<U2'), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[2]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8))
  (array(['Ari'], dtype='<U3'), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[3]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8))]]
a.dtype = [('name', 'O'), ('transitionIdx', 'O'), ('mapIdx', 'O'), ('isStruct', 'O')]
```

However, I cannot recreate any of the "array( [[ array( [[ array( [[" nesting.  How could this data structure be recreated?

**EDIT**

Per @t.o. and @hpaulj suggestions below, I created a script to traverse the structure and print out the array types and shapes:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

mat = scipy.io.loadmat( "simulink_model_input.mat", mat_dtype=True )

def traverse( mat_str ):
    mat = eval( mat_str )
    if type( mat ) not in [str,np.str_]:
        print( f"{mat_str} type: {type(mat)} shape: {np.shape(mat)}, dtype: {mat.dtype}" )
        traverse( mat_str + "[0]" )

traverse( "mat['rtp']['internal']" )
```

Output:

```
mat['rtp']['internal'] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (1, 1), dtype: object
mat['rtp']['internal'][0] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (1,), dtype: object
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (1, 1), dtype: [('tunedParameters', 'O')]
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (1,), dtype: [('tunedParameters', 'O')]
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.void'> shape: (), dtype: [('tunedParameters', 'O')]
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0][0][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (1, 1), dtype: object
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0][0][0][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (1,), dtype: object
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (1, 2), dtype: [('name', 'O'), ('transitionIdx', 'O'), ('mapIdx', 'O'), ('isStruct', 'O')]
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (2,), dtype: [('name', 'O'), ('transitionIdx', 'O'), ('mapIdx', 'O'), ('isStruct', 'O')]
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.void'> shape: (), dtype: [('name', 'O'), ('transitionIdx', 'O'), ('mapIdx', 'O'), ('isStruct', 'O')]
mat['rtp']['internal'][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape: (1,), dtype: <U2
```

However, I'm still unclear how to proceed.  If I can just understand how to get one level of nesting, I can (hopefully) manage the rest.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to recreate the structure of the array you are importing. You can just look at the shape of the imported array with `np.shape()` and build an array of zeros with it: `np.zeros(np.shape(<imported array>))`.

Comment: You may need to create one or more layers of `np.empty(shape, object)`, and assign elements.  That's the most general way of creating object dtype arrays will full control over the shape.